# VB.NET Button clicks stuff in webbrowser1

Tags: vb.net

How can i make it where you click button 1 and on a page like www.youtube.com/shanedawsontv in webbrowser1 it will click the text Add as friend cause they don't have ids for that please help

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to use the WebBrowser Control's DocumentText Property to get the HTML of the page so that you can parse the required HTTP request required to add the user as a friend.  That's likely to be no easy task with YouTube as it will probably be using hidden fields and Javascript (from a separate .js file) to make the request.